# ActionBarSherlock - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, runtime-error

Question related to `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application` have been asked many times on StackOverflow but my problem is a little different.

I am trying to implement ActionBarSherlock in my application. Everything works fine if I create a blank SherlockActivity like this:

```
public class MainActionBarActivity extends SherlockActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
SearchView.OnSuggestionListener {

    private Object mSuggestionsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_action_bar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        boolean isLight = true;

        //Create the search view
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search in MyWord¦");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);

//        if (mSuggestionsAdapter == null) {
//            MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);
//            cursor.addRow(new String[]{"1", "'Murica"});
//            cursor.addRow(new String[]{"2", "Canada"});
//            cursor.addRow(new String[]{"3", "Denmark"});
//            mSuggestionsAdapter = new SuggestionsAdapter(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), cursor);
//        }

//        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSuggestionsAdapter);

        menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.abs__ic_search_api_holo_light : R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);


//     MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
//     inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_action_bar, menu);
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        createSearchView();

       // Handle item selection
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.action_search:
             // do s.th.
             return true;

          default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }


    private void createSearchView() {
        //Create the search view
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countriesâ€¦");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
        String[] COLUMNS = {"A","B","C"};

//        if (mSuggestionsAdapter == null) {
//            MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);
//            cursor.addRow(new String[]{"1", "'Murica"});
//            cursor.addRow(new String[]{"2", "Canada"});
//            cursor.addRow(new String[]{"3", "Denmark"});
//            //mSuggestionsAdapter = new SuggestionsAdapter(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), cursor);
//        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

and Manifest file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jakhar.actionbar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name="com.jakhar.actionbar.MainActionBarActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But the problem arises when I call some other class from its onCreate method.
At first, it does not let some of my classes to get imported in MainActionBarActivity class. If I import them manually then calling them creates problem.

I sometimes get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application` this error and sometimes I get `ClassDefNotFoundError`. Any idea to help me out.

**Using ActionBarSherlock:** I am adding `ActionBarSherlock` as dependancy project under Project->Properties->Android.

Comment: are you add your  actiobbarSherlock as jar in your lib ??

Comment: I am adding ActionBarSherlock as dependancy project under Project->Properties->Android.
I am updating this information in the question also.

Comment: ClassDefNotFoundError this error when i face it i restart the eclipse and it work well try this may help you

Comment: I have done so. I cleaned project, restarted eclipse.